# adding styling to hyperlink tags in a CSS component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am trying to add styling to hyperlinks in my [CSS compoment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_css.htm). Normally on HTML, I would have done it as follows:

```
<style>
a:link, a:visited { 
  color: /* browser's internal value */;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: auto;
}
</style>
```

I trying to add the above stying to my [CSS component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_css.htm) as follows:

```
THIS a:link, a:visited { 
      color: /* browser's internal value */;
      text-decoration: underline;
      cursor: auto;
}
```

The aura Lightning component does not like my code, and complaints with the following error:

> Deployment Failed FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION - Issue(s) found by CSS
>   Parser (c.MarkUpPreview):  Unable to parse remaining declaration value
>   '(internal value)' (did you forget a semicolon?): at line 2, column 12
>   near '»(internal value)'  : Source

Any idea how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Thanks to @poz I also learned something new today, you can comma separate tags by making sure to add `.THIS` after the comma and a space:
New proposed solution:

```
.THIS a:link, .THIS a:visited {
      color: ;/* browser's internal value */
      text-decoration: underline;
      cursor: auto;
}
```

Hi I think you just have some syntax issue here:

Please review and try the following:

Note the `.` prior to THIS, and no comma between link and visited props.

Depending on your lightning version you may need to use the following:

```
.THIS a:link {
      color: ;/* browser's internal value */
      text-decoration: underline;
      cursor: auto;
}

.THIS a:visited {
      color: ;/* browser's internal value */
      text-decoration: underline;
      cursor: auto;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your CSS selector to

```
.THIS a:link, .THIS a:visited
```

As Brandon mentioned, you need a `.` in front of `THIS` (this is a CSS class selector).

However, you also need to prefix the second `a:visited` selector with `.THIS` to maintain the same scope.